# Weak convergence implies boundedness in norm vector space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence in the normed vector space $(X,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ and let $x\in X$. Show that the following are equivalent.

1. $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$
2. The sequence $(\Vert x_n \Vert)_{n\geq1}$ is bounded.

**My solution:**

$x_n \rightharpoonup x$ is equivalent to $\iota(x_n)\rightharpoonup \iota(x)$ in the weak$^{\ast}$ topology. Where $\iota$ is the canonical embedding between $X$ and $X^{\ast \ast}$ the bidual space. Since $\iota(x_n)$ is a bounded linear operator from $X^{\ast}\to \mathbb{R}$. We have that $(<\iota(x_n),x^{\ast}>)_{n\geq 1}$ converges and is pointwise bounded, so by the uniform boundedness theorem we have that $(<\iota(x_n),x^{\ast}>)_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded.
\begin{equation}
\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\Vert \iota (x_n)\Vert<\infty \Leftrightarrow \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\Vert x_n\Vert<\infty
\end{equation}

**Questions:** I'm not sure whether my solution is rigorous? I'm not sure to know why $(<\iota(x_n),x^{\ast}>)_{n\geq 1}$ is pointwise bounded?

Comment: 2. does not imply 1..

Comment: That would mean that my last assertion is wrong? the one with $\Leftrightarrow$ ?

Comment: Is at least the other direction correct?

Comment: Yes, that works. But it might be a bit clearer if you stated $(i(x_n))$ is pointwise bounded in $X^{**}$ (since $ i(x_n) (x^*)$ converges for any $x^*\in X^*$). So $(i(x_n))$ is norm bounded in $X^{**}$, whence $(x_n)$ is norm bounded in $X$.

Comment: Ok great thank you @DavidMitra ! May I ask you why the other direction does not work?

Comment: For example, the standard unit vectors in $\ell_1$ are bounded in norm, but not weakly convergent.

Comment: @DavidMitra I know of a partial converse in Hilbert space setting. Let $H$ be Hilbert and $D \subset H$ a dense subset of $H$. Then, $x_n \rightharpoonup x \iff \|x_n\| \le M$ for some constant $M$ and $\langle y, x_n \rangle \to \langle y, x \rangle$ for all $y \in D$. Do you know if there is a similar result when our space isn't Hilbert?

Comment: It seems that the title asks about the implication $1. \Rightarrow 2.$ while the body asks about the equivalence (which does not hold, as David pointed out).